# Do Cable Connectors/Terminal Blocks impact power requirements?

Tags: power, connector, resistance

I am planning on using a bunch of spare ego-T parts to build some mods and was thinking of hooking some AA battery block via some Cable Connectors/Terminal Blocks to an LED, Button and 510 Threaded head.

I know that the 510 will be taking a 1.8 Ohm cartomizer and needs to run at roughly 3.7 volts and just less than 2Amps at the head and I want to be sitting pretty at arround 6 to 8 watts in the cart. Will I be adding any significant resistance that I need to take into account by using Cable Connector Blocks?

I plan to use the blocks just because I can make and remake my set up until I have something I am happy with and also because I really do suck at soldering.

Comment: Smoking is bad for your health. Terminal blocks do not add significant resistance at 2A. And unless the AAs are NiMH, their voltage varies quite a lot during discharge.

Comment: That's why I switched to eCigs (so much healthier and a good way to give up). so the takeaway here appears to be that if I use blocks to connect with I should not worry about any change in power use vs soldering the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal blocks need to be rated for the current they will handle (otherwise they can melt).  For power levels you'd see in an ecigarette, pretty much any will work.

Your bigger problem will be using AA batteries.  Most Alkaline AA batteries will not work very well at high currents.  Particularly cheap ones like dollar store AAs - they are meant for remote controls and other things that draw very little power.  That's why ecigarettes typically use lithium ion batteries.  At high currents, the battery's voltage will drop very quickly.

High quality rechargable batteries handle this a little better - I had a 4xAA mod using PowerEx rechargeable batteries that worked fairly well, but not nearly as well as a single 14500 Lion cell.